# printing open files of current process

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, file-descriptor

I need to find the open files of the current process in C Linux.  So far all I could figure out was current -> task_struct... then there aren't a log of resources...eventually I'm supposed to get to `open_fds`?  Also, is the endpoint a bitmap file?  How would you get the open files from the bitmap structure or some other weird structure?

Comment: Do you need to do this in the kernel? If not, take a look at `/proc/$pid/fd`.

Comment: or simply (from inside your process) in `/proc/self/fd/` or `/proc/self/fdinfo/`- both are [pseudo-] directories.

Comment: @user963070: urfffff... Why don't you tell us in the _question_ what it is that you're trying to do, and show us the code where you have that `current->task_struct` so that we didn't have to be psychic and guess that you forgot to add the kernel tag?

Comment: struck tast_struct *task;                                                     for (task = current; task != &init_task; task = task->parent){           printk("%s", task->xxxxopenFileNamexxxxxx);  }  don't know what inside x's should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the command line `lsof`

in C, something like this:

Here is the commented code of a program that prints on screen a list of its own open files:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main() {
    // the directory we are going to open
    DIR           *d;

    // max length of strings
    int maxpathlength=256;

    // the buffer for the full path
    char path[maxpathlength];

    // /proc/PID/fs contains the list of the open file descriptors among the respective filenames
    sprintf(path,"/proc/%i/fd/",getpid() );

    printf("List of %s:\n",path);

    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(path);
    if (d) {
        //loop for each file inside d
        while1 != NULL) {

            //let's check if it is a symbolic link
            if (dir->d_type == DT_LNK) {

                const int maxlength = 256;

                # string returned by readlink()
                char hardfile[maxlength];

                #string length returned by readlink()
                int len;

                # tempath will contain the current filename among the fullpath
                char tempath[maxlength];

                sprintf(tempath,"%s%s",path,dir->d_name);
                if2!=-1) {
                    hardfile[len]='\0';
                        printf("%s -> %s\n", dir->d_name,hardfile);

                } else
                    printf("error when executing readlink() on %s\n",tempath);

            }
        }

        closedir(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is from: http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=229 , which is cached here: http://tinyurl.com/6qlv2nj

See:

[How to use lsof(List Opened Files) in a C/C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470121/how-to-use-lsoflist-opened-files-in-a-c-c-application)

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/c-library-for-lsof-183332/

you could also use the `lsof` command via a `popen` call.

Comment: probably not. The original poster mention "the current process in C".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : that's "a list of its own open files" .. that's what the code example does.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: it doesn't get much more C than this. This is simply a great answer.

Comment: I was looking for something that used current->task_struct... because that's what I've been trying to do, and I want to know how...

Comment: The given code is wrong. Construct while1 does not exist in C, and 'dir' pointer is not assigned.

Comment: yeah - that looks like a typo

Answer (score 4):

By default, the kernel allows each process to open `NR_OPEN_DEFAULT` files. This value is defined
in include/linux/sched.h with the default setting of `BITS_PER_LONG`. On 32-bit systems, the initial number of files is therefore 32; 64-bit systems can handle 64 files simultaneously.

in file.h

```c
    struct files_struct {
      /*
       * read mostly part
       */
      atomic_t count;
      struct fdtable *fdt;
      struct fdtable fdtab;
      /*
       * written part on a separate cache line in SMP
       */
      spinlock_t file_lock ____cacheline_aligned_in_smp;
      int next_fd;
      struct embedded_fd_set close_on_exec_init;
      struct embedded_fd_set open_fds_init;
      struct file * fd_array[NR_OPEN_DEFAULT];
    };
```

In the kernel, each opened file is represented by a file descriptor that acts as a position index for
a process-specific array (task_struct->files->fd_array). This array contains an instance of the abovementioned file structure with all necessary file information for each opened file.

By looping through `fd_array`, you can get info of all open files by the process.