# Can the NETLINK/SOCK_DIAG interface be used to listen for `listen()` and `close()` events of said socket?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, netlink

I've been gleaning information about the NETLINK socket which allows us to listen on what is happening in *socket land*. It seems to very partially work, but I'm wondering whether I missed something.

I'm using C++, although of course all the NETLINK is pure C, so here we have mainly C headers. The following code has three main parts:

1. Binding

   First I create a `socket()` and `bind()` it.

   The `bind()` is kind of magical. When using a bound NETLINK socket, you start receiving events without having to have a polling setup (which is why I'm trying to do this, to avoid polling for when a socket starts listening for connections).

   I put -1 in the `nl_groups` so that way all events are sent to my socket. But, at this point, I seem to only receive two of them: `TCP_ESTABLISHED` and `TCP_CLOSE`. The one I really would like to receive is the `TCP_LISTEN` and "not listening" (which apparently is not going to be available...)
2. Explicit Request

   I tried with an explicit request. I have it in the code below so you can see how I've done it. That request works as expected. I get an explicit reply if the socket exists or an error "No such file or directory" when the socket is closed. Great, except that mechanism means I'd be using a poll (i.e. I need my process to try over and over again on a timer until the socket is visible).

   ***Note:** the error when no one is listening is happening because the request is explicit, i.e. it includes the expected IP address and port that I'm interested in.*
3. Response

   The next part is a loop, which sits until a response is received. The `recvmsg()` call is blocking in this version, which is why it sits around in this test.

   If I sent my explicit request (see point 2. above), then, as I mentioned, I get a reply if another process is listening, otherwise I get an error saying it's not listening. The state is clearly set to 10 (`TCP_LISTEN`), so everything works as expected.

   When listening to all the events (-1 in the bind), the process will go on and receive more data as events happen. However, so far, the only events I've received are 1 and 7 (i.e. `TCP_ESTABLISHED` and `TCP_CLOSE`).

I used the following to compile my code:

```
g++ -Wall -o a test.cpp
```

Here is my test code with which I can reproduce my current results:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <linux/netlink.h>
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>
#include    <netinet/in.h>
#include    <linux/netlink.h>
#include    <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include    <linux/sock_diag.h>
#include    <linux/inet_diag.h>

int
main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // socket / bind

    int d = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG);
    if(d < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "error: could not create RAW socket.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_nl addr = {};
    addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    addr.nl_pid = getpid();
    addr.nl_groups = -1;
           // You can find these flags in Linux source:
           //
           //     "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-147/include/net/tcp_states.h
           //
           //   (1 <<  7)   // TCPF_CLOSE
           // | (1 <<  8)   // TCPF_CLOSE-WAIT
           // | (1 << 10)   // TCPF_LISTEN
           // | (1 << 11)   // TCPF_CLOSING
           // ;
    if(bind(d, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(&addr), sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        perror("bind failure\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // request

    struct sockaddr_nl nladdr = {};

    nladdr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;

    struct nl_request
    {
        struct nlmsghdr         f_nlh;
        struct inet_diag_req_v2 f_inet;
    };

    nl_request req = {};

    req.f_nlh.nlmsg_len = sizeof(req);
    req.f_nlh.nlmsg_type = SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY;
    req.f_nlh.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST;
    req.f_inet.sdiag_family = AF_INET;
    req.f_inet.sdiag_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    req.f_inet.idiag_ext = 0;
    req.f_inet.pad = 0;
    req.f_inet.idiag_states = 0;
    req.f_inet.id.idiag_sport = htons(4998);
    req.f_inet.id.idiag_dport = 0;
    req.f_inet.id.idiag_src[0] = htonl(0x0A00020A);
    req.f_inet.id.idiag_dst[0] = 0;
    req.f_inet.id.idiag_if = 0;
    req.f_inet.id.idiag_cookie[0] = INET_DIAG_NOCOOKIE;
    req.f_inet.id.idiag_cookie[1] = INET_DIAG_NOCOOKIE;

    struct iovec vector = {};

    vector.iov_base = &req;
    vector.iov_len = sizeof(req);

    struct msghdr msg = {};

    msg.msg_name = &nladdr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(nladdr);
    msg.msg_iov = &vector;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

    int const r(sendmsg(d, &msg, 0));
    if(r < 0)
    {
        perror("sendmsg");
        return 1;
    }

    // response

    struct sockaddr_nl r_nladdr = {};

    r_nladdr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;

    struct iovec r_vector = {};

    long buf[8192 / sizeof(long)];
    r_vector.iov_base = buf;
    r_vector.iov_len = sizeof(buf);

    for(int i(1);; ++i)
    {
        struct msghdr r_msg = {};

        r_msg.msg_name = &r_nladdr;
        r_msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(r_nladdr);
        r_msg.msg_iov = &r_vector;
        r_msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

        //std::cout << "wait for message...\n";

        ssize_t size(recvmsg(d, &r_msg, 0));
        if(size < 0)
        {
            perror("recvmsg");
            return 1;
        }

        if(size == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "end of message stream received." << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        //std::cout << "got message #" << i << ": size = " << size << std::endl;

        struct nlmsghdr const * h(reinterpret_cast<struct nlmsghdr *>(buf));

        if(!NLMSG_OK(h, size))
        {
            std::cerr << "NLMSG_OK() says there is an error." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        do
        {
            if(h->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_DONE)
            {
                std::cout << "explicit end of message stream received (NLMSG_DONE)." << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            if(h->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_ERROR)
            {
                struct nlmsgerr const * err(reinterpret_cast<struct nlmsgerr const *>(NLMSG_DATA(h)));

                if(h->nlmsg_len < NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(*err)))
                {
                    std::cerr << "unknown NLMSG_ERROR received." << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    // here is the location display an error when trying to get an
                    // event about the LISTEN and no one is listening on that port.
                    //
                    errno = -err->error;
                    perror("NLMSG_ERROR:");
                }
                return 1;
            }

            if(h->nlmsg_type != SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY)
            {
                std::cerr << "unexpected message type (h->nlmsg_type) "
                    << h->nlmsg_type
                    << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            //std::cout << "------- sock_diag info!\n";

            struct inet_diag_msg const * k_msg(reinterpret_cast<struct inet_diag_msg const *>(NLMSG_DATA(h)));
            if(h->nlmsg_len < NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(*k_msg)))
            {
                std::cerr << "unexpected message length (h->nlmsg_len) "
                    << h->nlmsg_type
                    << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            switch(k_msg->idiag_state)
            {
            case 1:
            case 7:
                break;

            default:
            {
                std::uint32_t const src_ip(ntohl(k_msg->id.idiag_src[0]));
                std::uint32_t const dst_ip(ntohl(k_msg->id.idiag_dst[0]));
                std::cout << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_family = " << static_cast<int>(k_msg->idiag_family) << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_state = " << static_cast<int>(k_msg->idiag_state) << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_timer = " << static_cast<int>(k_msg->idiag_timer) << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_retrans = " << static_cast<int>(k_msg->idiag_retrans) << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->id.idiag_sport = " << ntohs(k_msg->id.idiag_sport) << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->id.idiag_dport = " << ntohs(k_msg->id.idiag_dport) << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->id.idiag_src[0] = " << ((src_ip >> 24) & 255)
                                << "." << ((src_ip >> 16) & 255) << "." << ((src_ip >> 8) & 255) << "." << (src_ip & 255) << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->id.idiag_dst[0] = " << ((dst_ip >> 24) & 255)
                                << "." << ((dst_ip >> 16) & 255) << "." << ((dst_ip >> 8) & 255) << "." << (dst_ip & 255) << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->id.idiag_if = " << k_msg->id.idiag_if << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->id.idiag_cookie[0] = " << k_msg->id.idiag_cookie[0] << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->id.idiag_cookie[1] = " << k_msg->id.idiag_cookie[1] << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_expires = " << k_msg->idiag_expires << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_rqueue = " << k_msg->idiag_rqueue << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_wqueue = " << k_msg->idiag_wqueue << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_uid = " << k_msg->idiag_uid << "\n"
                    << "inet_diag_msg->idiag_inode = " << k_msg->idiag_inode << "\n"
                    << "\n";
            }
                break;

            }

            // next message
            //
            h = NLMSG_NEXT(h, size);
        }
        while(NLMSG_OK(h, size));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To test that IP:port combo, I simply used the `nc` command like so:

```
nc -l 10.0.2.10 4998
```

You of course need the 10.0.2.10 IP on one of your interfaces for this to work.

**My question is:**

Did I do something wrong that I do not receive `TCP_LISTEN` events on that socket unless explicitly requested?

*P.S. Just in case, I tried to run this test app as root. Same results.*

Comment: My socket foo is very out of date, but I think you have shown us the receiving/snooping bits here, is anything actually trying to send data to that port?

Comment: I would add that, when in doubt, do not try running as root especially with untested network code.

Comment: @jwdonahue Note that's just a NETLINK which talks to the kernel, so very local. Also I wrote the code so I trust it enough. Now, if I remove the `switch(k_msg->idiag_state)` and let all cases go through the `default: ...` case, then I see the established and close events. So I think the loop generally works. But somehow doesn't want to send messages for the new `TCP_LISTEN` in said loop.

Comment: @AlexisWilke did you manage to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @andrea.marangoni Unfortunately, I have not seen any movement on that. I am thinking that newer versions of Linux may get better. I tested on 22.10 and it still fails. Same way.

Comment: @AlexisWilke try to follow the ss source code (might be dated because it doesn't compile) but I have found it very useful for my usecase --> [ss.c](https://github.com/sivasankariit/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c)